# Content on social media platforms

Tags: discussion, promotion

Now that we are gearing ourselves up with having more people joining "the team" in managing the social media aspect of Web Applications (Twitter and Google+), we should start having some discussion about what goes on such platforms.

As this is written by humans and not robots, I do not really want to see only featuring questions and nothing else on such pages. So the question is, what shall we add to these pages? Who is going to be in charge of what?

*(Do realize the striking similarity between these media platforms and having an actual blog on BlogOverflow.)*

Comment: One re-occurring item could be the weekly updates on hot questions and answers and/or unanswered questions (not answer worthy..)

Comment: Engaging in each media channel would be the way to go, e.g. retweeting certain Twitter users and/or @-mentioning without looking like spam. Giving updates on the popular Web Applications can work as well. Taking advantage of #hashtags also will be a good idea. As to who is being charge of what, it's all up to you and @Jacob and whoever else wants to join along. Until we actually have a blog, you can pretty much do whatever you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible content that should go into our social media pages. Please feel free to edit this answer, comment or post as another answer.

### Feature questions

We can feature popular questions based on the "hot" tab on the main page. We can also re-tweet questions posted to the robot-based @StackWebApps Twitter account (though we need to manually copy it over to Google+

Since this is quite manual, we can also select questions that are popular but have yet to be answered since months before.

#### Managers

- Jacob Jan
- *(add your name here)*

### New products/Popular closing products

This might be a possible addition to the social media pages where we select a new web application that deserves to be recognized. It can be just a short description and a link to the website (we can even base this on new tags created on the main site).

As for closing products, we can provide a link to a general question to aid users in migrating their data to an alternative, especially if the product is very popular and there is some discussion on the Internet about it.

#### Managers

- <strike>Hydra</strike>
- *(add your name here)*

### Other ideas

Below is a list of what we *can* consider adding to the above list:

- Guides to products
- Featured users of the site

Comment: Apologies, community wiki posts do not work like how the original site does, so you need at least 2,000 reputation to edit. Feel free to comment here if you are interested though.

Comment: how do we find the new web apps ;)

Comment: @Sathya That's something people can post, I recon.

Comment: I got bold and started writing some features to recent popular questions :D