# Web Applications Google Plus Page - Update

Tags: support, statistics, promotion

In **[this](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2338/29140)** post, here on Meta, we (Hydra) asked for "Managers" for the Web Applications Google+ fan page.

Since the end of February 2013, I'm active on the Web Applications Google+ fan page, collecting active users on Web Applications that have a Google+ account as well.

Here are some stats per 25-07-2013:

- Circled 100 people (5% found us !!)
- 40 +1'd the page
- 28 circled us back
- 31 posts (not all shared publicly)

Here are some stats per 01-01-2015:

- Circled 230 people
- 88 circled us back

Are there still people interested in doing what I do? To pump up the volume, spread the word, get questions answered, love to hangout on G+ as well? If yes, leave a message.

@phwd: can you remove Hydra as a manager from the G+ page please?
@Al: your invitation. as a g+ manager is still pending...

Comment: Couldn't see the link to the page - https://plus.google.com/u/0/115325506027680380975/posts

Comment: i can spread the word ,through my blogger and g+ pages

Comment: I didn't know you had this! I am Ellie K on Google+, will look for you and circle right now. Thank you, this is great! I would like to do this, what you do!

Comment: I found and circled you! Yay! And spread the good word, here https://plus.google.com/u/0/115879002218399415085/posts/gNt1yY4ufqP  By hangout on Google+, do you mean do "Hang Outs"? I haven't done that, feel shy about that. It involves web cams, right? I do like spending time on Google+ and I love StackExchange.

Comment: @phwd can you add Feral as well, please?

Comment: Added Ellie K (Feral)

Comment: I used the link given by @FeralOink but can't tell whether I've added myself successfully...

Comment: @phwd Thank you!

Comment: @FeralOink I'm batpigandme pretty much everywhere!

Comment: @FeralOink You're not responding to the g+ messages I'm sending to you.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I'm sorry. It wasn't by intent. I lost 47,000 Gmail messages, but seem to have recovered them yesterday. I'm more responsive on Twitter, and here ;o) than Google+, I confess. I will go check and respond to you now, ASAP. Again, my apologies.

Comment: @FeralOink No need to apologize !! I'm not that responsive on Twitter (because I have no account). 47000 mails....puh....

Comment: I closed this question as Google+ was retired. While it's still available for Google Workspace users (now named Currents) this service will be retired soon too.